# Import pycharm project into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am using Pycharm to develop a python package and would like to use Jupyter notebooks to interact with the modules.

My project structure is as follows :

```
project/notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb
project/module/__init__.py
project/module/core.py
project/tests/...
```

I run `my_notebook.ipynb` in the browser but cannot figure out how to import the content of the python module. Anything like `from module import foo` does not work out of the box. I came accross [this blog post](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2015/05/11/using-ipython-notebooks-and-pycharm-together/) which involves installing the source code as an editable Pip package but I am wondering if there is another way to make it work that does not involves installing the package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get that directory into your path inside the notebook:

eg:

```
import sys

# make sure to use position 1
sys.path.insert(1, "/Users/foo/bar/project/")
from module.core import foo
```

It's important to use position 1 as using position 0 may break sys.path: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

**Also note** you should make sure you are using the **same** virtualenv (or conda env) for your notebook that your pycharm project is using, or else you might have unanticipated conflicts

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is bad practice to hardcode a specific path into the notebook code. Instead I would add the root project folder to PYTHONPATH when starting up your Jupyter notebook server, either directly from the project folder like so

`` env PYTHONPATH=`pwd` jupyter notebook ``

or if you are starting it up from somewhere else, like so

`env PYTHONPATH=/Users/foo/bar/project/ jupyter notebook`